# Can't acces private members in a object of same type

Tags: c++, templates, char

The problem is in title, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Pair
{
    T1 first;
    T2 second;

 public:
    Pair(T1 _first = NULL, T2 _second = NULL) : first(_first), second(_second) {}
    Pair(const Pair<T1, T2>&  other) : first(other.first),  second(other.second) {}
};

template<>
class Pair<char*, char*>
{
    char* first;
    char* second;
public:
     Pair(char* _first = NULL, char* _second = NULL) : first(_strdup(_first)), second(_strdup(_second)) {}
     Pair(const Pair<char*, char*>& other) : first(_strdup(other.first)),  second(_strdup(other.second)) {}
};

int main()
{
    Pair<short, char> pair;
    Pair<char*, char*> pair2;
}
```

5   IntelliSense: member "Pair::first" (declared at line 20) is inaccessible
6   IntelliSense: member "Pair::second" (declared at line 21) is inaccessible

So what, is this exclusive for template classes with pointers as data members, objects of same class can't access them? And what is the solution? I've also tried creating member functions(before this constructor) that return these pointers, and then use them, but then I've got some other error.

Not sure may this be a question duplicate, there is a question with a similar title but I didn't understand the answer...

Don't advise to use std::string instead of char*, I would if I could ;)

Comment: That's a problem of the intellisense. It compiles doesn't it?

Comment: The example compiles OK on VS2015. Also, `T1 _first = NULL` and `T2 _second = NULL` are probably not doing what you think they are.

Comment: Can't reproduce this error in g++. Are you sure you're getting a compile error?

Comment: Intellisense is *not* the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even try running when I saw the errors, shame on me :)

Comment: Don't forget the Rule of Five - make sure you add all the other members for `Pair<char*, char*>`, given that you're managing memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine, IntelliSense is wrong.

Although you may want to consider the fact that not all types can be initialized with `NULL`. If you want a default constructor, use `Pair() = default;`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even try running when I saw the errors.